# Multiplying Matrices by Using Pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, multiplication

I am trying to create a method which is like this: 
`void Multiply(double *A, double *B, double *C, int N);`

It is a function that computes `C = A * B`.
A, B and C are NxN(square) matrices and I have to do it by pointers.

The code I have written is like the following:

```
int Multiply(double *A, double *B, double *C, int N){
    int i,j,k;
    double sum;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
         sum = 0;
         for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {

            sum = sum + (*(A+i*N+k)) * (*(B+k*N+i));
         }
         *(C+i*N+j) = sum;
      }
   }
}
```

It doesn't cause any errors and also it is not working.

I can't see the problem. Please can anybody help?

Comment: Shouldn't your `sum` be a `double`?

Comment: `A` is `NXN` matrix and represented by `double *`. sounds fishy...

Comment: When working with arrays, you have to remember that they are indexed from zero to size - 1, seeing your loop condition being less-than-*or-equal* I suspect you are going to be reading from outside the boundaries of the arrays.

Comment: Your loops should make the upper bound exclusive: Replace `<=` with `<`.

Comment: And you are assigning to `B`, where you want to assign to `C`.

Comment: You should prefer array syntax over pointer arithmetric: `(*(A+i*N+k))` -> `A[i*N+k]`. Much simpler.

Comment: You're not using `j` in the calculation of `sum`.

Comment: Show the calling code as well as input, output and expected output.

Comment: I assigned the sum as double and fixed the array boundary. I supposed to assign C to sum it was a careless mistake. Still I cannot get it working.

Comment: Try returning something... That might help.

Comment: I have codes in the main to test it and %100 I am sure that is working. So at this point returning won't solve anything.

Comment: With a small matrix, run in a debugger and step through the code line by line to see what actually happens.

Comment: And regarding the return value, the function is specified to return an `int`. If the caller uses that returned value, and you don't actually return anything, then you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i,j` element of `C` is the row `i` of `A` multiply by the `j` column of `B`. The kernel of your loops should be:

```
sum = sum + (*(A+i*N+k)) * (*(B+k*N+j));
```